# Is there a way to "rate limit" message notifications in slack?

Tags: slack

By default slack sends a message when the user presses the enter key (this can be changed to send on Ctrl-Enter, but most people don't).  So when someone is sending me something that they break into lines manually, I get a flurry of "bloop" notification noises that drive me crazy.

I do want to get notified when a new message is sent, but there's no reason to be spammed with "bloop" every couple seconds.

Can I rate limit/throttle those notifications somehow?  I don't see much reason for more than one every 10 or 15 seconds.  Maybe longer - ideally I could configure it however I want.

Comment: Here a recursive answer https://twitter.com/gianiaz/status/1582265565045198848